# How to add XML string to Nokogiri Builder

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an existing Nokogiri builder and some xml nodes in a string from a different source. How can I add this string to my builder?

```
str = "<options><cc>true</cc></options>"
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |q|
  q.query do |f|
    f.name "awesome"
    f.filter str
  end
end
```

This escapes str into something like:

```
xml.to_xml
=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<query>\n  <name>awesome</name>\n  <filter>&lt;options&gt;&lt;cc&gt;true&lt;/cc&gt;&lt;/options&gt;</filter>\n</query>\n"
```

I have found many, many similar things, including nesting builders and using the << operator, but nothing works to insert a full xml node tree into a builder block.
How can I make that string into real nodes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What problems did you find using `<<`? This works for me:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |q|
  q.query do |f|
    f.name "awesome"
    f << str
  end
end
```

and avoids using the private `insert` method.

Answer (score 0):

And, as usual, I found the answer shortly after posting...

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |q|
  q.query do |f|
    f.name "awesome"
    f.__send__ :insert, Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse( str )
  end
end.to_xml
```

Gives you

```
=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<query>\n  <name>awesome</name>\n  <options>\n    <cc>true</cc>\n  </options>\n</query>\n"
```

EDIT: This way worked for me when << failed for some unknown reason. However, as others have pointed out it works by directly accessing the :insert method which was intended to be protected. Consider it both "bad practice" and a last resort.

Comment: That's doing it the hard way. See the answer @matt gave, which uses the [`<<`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html#method-i-3C-3C) operator to append raw XML.

Comment: one update nokogiri gem and a bundle later and the @matt syntax works great. I don't know what to say because I tried using << so many ways before!

Comment: It's a pretty good idea to keep your gems updated in the Ruby world. Where we'd lag behind the bleeding edge in other languages, often it's good to stay pretty current with Ruby.